# Saving data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

so i have a .js file that 2 different jsp pages call.

`.js` file contains:

```
var savedObj;

function A(obj){ savedObj = obj);

function B(){ alert(savedObj);
```

`X.jsp` file calls function A such that a DOM element `onchange = functionA(this);`

`Y.jsp` file calls function B such that body `onload = function B`

For some reason, my debugging in function A shows that the assignment of `savedObj = obj` worked correctly, but in `function B`, `savedObj` printed out null.

Thanks guys

Comment: If I am getting your question right, `function B` gets called before the `function A` and since `savedObj` gets value only when you call `function A`, its alert `null` on `onload` of body

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer, I guessed he is misinterpreting the result

Comment: no, function B is called after a form submission

Comment: What is `function B{`??? You mean `function B(){`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a cookie to store the value is certainly the best way to make the value persist across various pages.  If you don't want to go into cookies, you could use javascript to write the new page in place of the current page and keep the value, but it's messy and you're better off taking the time to learn cookies.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your *function B* is being called when the body of the JSP has finished loading.  This will happen before any change event on a specific DOM element.

If you need *function B* to have the updated *savedObj*, you will need to wait to call it until after the change event is fired on your DOM element.

**Note:** this assumes that your JSPs are being included in the same rendered page, if they are not, this is happening because JavaScript state is not persisted from page to page

Comment: yes it seems that they do not persist...is there a workaround? or i have to refactor big time?

Comment: To persist from page to page on the client side, store the value in a cookie.